# what command can find codec of audio file by ffmpeg.exe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ffmpeg

I am using command line ffmpeg.exe
Can any one tell me about some commands for:

1. how to get audio file codec.
2. how to get bitrate of audio file
   etc.
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't strike me as a programming question. You should ask it on superuser.

Comment: @Flimzy `Can I find id3 tags by javascript?` is a programming question. I get the impression they're trying to call ffmpeg via a web interface. Thought I agree, it's a poor attempt at asking questions

Comment: Ah, perhaps I should have flagged it as "Not a real question" rather than "Off-topic" then.

Comment: Yeah, since theres no option for crazy list of questions :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most of this is detailed, unsurprisingly in the ffmpeg documentation: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html

`Can i find id3 tags by javascript`

Signs point to yes: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript

Consider doing basic research before posting lists of questions. https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Basically i want to fetch cover art of songs.